# `UTF16Index()` or `UTF16Index.init(encodedOffset:)` for Xcode 8/9 support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deprecated

I'm on a development team that's supporting both Xcode 8 and Xcode 9.

I was developing a feature that used `String.UTF16Index(range.location)` in Xcode 8. When I upgraded to Xcode 9, that resulted in the error `'init' is deprecated`.

So in Xcode 9 I changed it to `UTF16Index.init(encodedOffset: range.lowerBound)`. However, now that doesn't work in Xcode 8 with the error `Argument labels '(encodedOffset:)' do not match any available overloads`.

Even if I could check the Xcode version and write different code, one of the lines would fail at compile time. How can I manage this? Or am I stuck waiting until we fully move to Xcode 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Version Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Compatibility.html) in the Swift documentation:

> NOTE
>
> When the Swift 4 compiler is working with Swift 3 code, it identifies its language version as 3.2. As a result, you can use conditional compilation blocks like #if swift(>=3.2) to write code that’s compatible with multiple versions of the Swift compiler.

In your case that would be

```
#if swift(>=3.2)
let idx = String.UTF16Index(encodedOffset: range.lowerBound)
#else
let idx = String.UTF16Index(range.location)
#endif
```

In Xcode 9 (Swift 4 or Swift 3.2 mode) only the first line is compiled,
and in Xcode 8 (Swift 3.1) only the second line is compiled.

**Update:** The use of `encodedOffset` is [considered harmful](https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/#use-of-stringindexencodedoffset-considered-harmful) and will be [deprecated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0241-string-index-explicit-encoding-offset.md) in Swift 5. Starting with Swift 4, the correct way to convert an `NSRange` to a `Range<String.Index>` is

```
let str = "abc"
let nsRange = NSRange(location: 2, length: 1)
let sRange = Range(nsRange, in: str)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can do a Swift version check to call the right API. But if you're calling this from multiple places then it might be easier to define a shim

```
#if swift(>=3.2)
// already correct
#else
extension String.UTF16Index {
    init(encodedOffset: Int) {
        self.init(encodedOffset)
    }
}
#endif
```

Now you can just write `String.UTF16Index(encodedOffset: range.lowerBound)` and in Xcode 8 it will call your shim.

Comment: Good idea! – Note that it should be `range.location` in order to compile with both Swift 3 and 4 (or add another shim for `NSRange.lowerbound`)